# how to increase more specificity external css over internal css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

how to increase specificity in external (fcomponents.css). in that css there are thousands of code need to change there will takes lots of time. if any other way to fix the issue without affecting internal body css?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
       body {
    display: block !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: var(--fw-regular);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

   .body button{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: yellow !important;
    background-color: #02010100;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: aqua;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 18px 35px 13px;
        }

        
        
    .body button:hover{
        color: #fff;
    background-color: #99a66d;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #99a66d;
        }
    </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/fcomponents.css">
    
</head>
<body class="body">
    <button onclick="()">Click ME!</button>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a higher specificity in the *external* CSS, so that it overwrites your internal CSS? Since you can't access and edit the external CSS, your only option would be to refactor your internal.

Comment: yeah body inherited css not affect external css. can we use css layer for above css overirde issue?